# Hibernate Criteria/Criterion with Restrictions equals non null values of POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, pojo

I have a POJO like this

```
public class Employee
{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  // setters and getters
}
```

Can i use the Criteria API which checks for equality on non null values of POJO

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setName("Xyz");
session.createCriteria(Employee.class).add(
         Restrictions.nonNullPropertiesEqual(emp) /* Imaginary method */);
```

rather than

```
session.createCriteria(Employee.class).add(   
         Restrictions.eq("name", "Xyz"));
```

So that i can accept POJO as a method argument and return the POJO(s) which matches the non null properties of POJO.

I'm using hibernate 4.3.8

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using java reflection API like this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

private void nonNullPropertiesEqual(Object obj){
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(obj.getClass());
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        cr.add(Restrictions.isNotNull(field.getName()));
    }
}
```

then you can call this method like this with any POJO

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
nonNullPropertiesEqual(emp);
```

this will put the restrictions on non NULL attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate [Example Criterion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html) can be used for this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
        .add(Example.create(employeeObjWithFewFieldsSet)
             .setPropertySelector(Example.NotNullPropertySelector.INSTANCE));
criteria.list();
```

Above query is popularly known as "Hibernate Query By Example (QBE)"

Beware, i have not tested this (as i no longer require). But will update here if i do.